# Smart Watch (Android & Apple) integration in Ionic Framework

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, wear-os, apple-watch

I am working on Ionic Framework from couple of months, I also checked out new Ionic version out 1.0.1. Actually I post this question regarding creating smart watch application in ionic framework.

Until now I Google and I just found this cordova plugin which interact with Apple watch https://github.com/20steps/cordova-plugin-watch. This is only support for iOs.

There are several cordova plugin available but I did't find any relevant answer or tutorial or blog using which I can learn smart watch integration. In native this task is easy but using same plugin and target both apple and android smart watch is more important and cost will be less for development.

Any help for this topic will be helpful. Thanks !

Comment: What's your problem/question, exactly?

Comment: @bgilham question is " How to develop smart watch application in Ionic Framework ?"

Comment: Some cursory Googling didn't turn anything up? Did you check the Ionic site? You probably can't.

Comment: If it is on Ionic , It will place at top results. I also go there page and check out their doc no relevant information.

Comment: Looks like you've got your answer, then.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried https://github.com/tgardner/cordova-androidwear in the meantime? There is an example on https://github.com/tgardner/cordova-androidwear-example too.