# Smart watch notifications Cordova plugin for both iOS and Android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am investigating pushing notifications from my Cordova (Ionic) application (ie running on a *smart phone*) to smart watches,  for **both** iOS and Android.

I found [this older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30258971/smart-watch-android-apple-integration-in-ionic-framework), but since a lot can change in 3 years, I thought I'd readdress this..

So, we seem to have iOS [here](https://github.com/20steps/cordova-plugin-watch), and Android [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-androidwear), but wondering if there is a plug in that supports both?

Otherwise, I assume we could use both plugins and select which we use depending on the platform?

Thanks in advance for any info

Comment: which version of ionic are you using? v1 or greater?

Comment: @rob Ionic 3 soon to upgrade to 4

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could find [this plugin](https://github.com/peterapps/Cordova-Smartwatch), of course.

> Cordova Smartwatch

According to this one, there seems to be *no suitable* plugin which supports both platforms(iOS & android) at the same time yet, I'm afraid.

There's also an [open topic](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/smartwatch-plugin/45217) for this problem in ionic forum.